# Trying to submit android form data via PHP POST METHOD

Tags: java, php, android, forms, http

I'm trying to create a form which is to send the information via a POST method.

```
public class PostData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yourdomain.com/serverside-script.php");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "01"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", params[0]));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                String op = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");//The response you get from your script
                return op;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //reset the message text field
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        msgTextField.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

But I am getting errors when I try to import HttpClient, HttpPost, BaseNameValuePair etc....

```
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
```

Please help!!

Comment: What are those errors exactly?

Comment: try adding `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'` in your dependency

Comment: add this line `android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }` to app `build.gradle` dependencies

Comment: you need to use.. HttpUrlConnection.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient` was deprecated in API Level **22** and removed in API Level **23**. You have to use `HttpURLConnection`.

**Docs how to use:-**

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection

**Example:-**

```
URL url = new URL("http://yoururl.com");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
        .appendQueryParameter("id", "01")
        .appendQueryParameter("message", params[0]);
String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(query);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();

conn.connect();
```

**But, If you still** want to use it, then you need to add additional dependencies for it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use okhttp rather than http clinet 
check here for okhttp post data.

https://www.studytutorial.in/android-okhttp-post-and-get-request-tutorial